# JMeter two(2) page login load test

Tags: authentication, jmeter, load-testing

I am very interested in using and mastering the JMeter tool. I am still at the beginning and I am stuck with this situation:

I wanted to load test an application but there is a login page with two pages. Basically you have to fill in forms on 2 pages. How do you do that in JMeter? I tested so far just 1 page process.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what you tried as you didn't provide any information. First try to record the login process - instruction here: https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf. If this will not work as expected then you can easily configure two proper requests and send them one by one - in a thread group add two sampler -> HTTP Request and configure accordingly. I assume that you know how the authentication process for your page looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the number of "pages" shouldn't matter as:

- in case if it is in fact one page 2nd part of which is not visible, i.e. via [CSS display:none property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)
- if these are really 2 pages, you need to maintains the session between them (an after the login as well). To do so:

  - make sure you have [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar)
  - if there are any mandatory dynamic parameters you need to extract them from 1st page, save into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and use as parameters for the 2nd page. The most commonly used test element for this is [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)